# php sql max where id2=$id2

Tags: php, max

i'm trying to find the highest number in my table (named huur) from column Borga but only for the user where the ID2 is equal to the number i have in the variable named $ID2. 
The highest number should go into the variable $hoogste_borg
this is the code i'm using, but i get invalid syntax error? what am i doing wrong?

```
<?php 
    $query="SELECT MAX('Borga') FROM huur ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1 WHERE ID2='$ID2'";
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
    $hoogste_borg=$row['Borga'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` must go after `WHERE` clauses. -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

```
SELECT MAX('Borga')
   FROM huur
   WHERE ID2='$ID2'
   ORDER BY ID DESC 
   LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
$query="SELECT MAX('BORGA') as Borga...";
```

Cause you want the 'Borga' field, but SQL return MAX('Borga')

If it doesn't work do this:

```
var_dump($row);
```

And show us the result :)